# XML Data management in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I learning  Xml data handling in .NET. I have the following XML format.

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>book 1</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>author 1</AUTHOR>       
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>book 2</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>author 2</AUTHOR>       
        <PRICE>20.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

I need to learn to add/edit/delete new books to the XML file. Could you please guide me on what all classes to explore for these functionality. I find lot of classes like `XmlDocument` `XmlTextWriter` etc. Some sites suggest to use LINQ as well. I am confused as to which was to go. Is there any good material I can refer to understand this.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of adding and removing elements using LINQ to XML:

```
// load the XML file into an XElement
XElement xml = XElement.Load(filePath);

// add a new book
xml.Add(
    new XElement("BOOK",
        new XElement("TITLE", "book 3"),
        new XElement("AUTHOR", "author 3"),
        new XElement("PRICE", 0.1),
        new XElement("YEAR", 2012)));

// remove a book that matches the desired title     
xml.Elements("BOOK").Where(x => x.Element("TITLE").Value == "book 1").Remove();

// to edit an existing element:
xml.Elements("BOOK")
    .Single(x => x.Element("TITLE").Value == "book 2") // take a single book
    .Element("AUTHOR").Value = "new author";  // and change its author field
```

Basically, use whatever you want, as long as you're comfortable with the technology. LINQ to SQL seems a bit easier, in my opinion.

Comment: That really helped. Thanks! I have another query. While iterating through the xDocument, I write the following to get to the root node. It is working fine, but not sure if it is the right way. `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
 XElement rootNode = (XElement)xDoc.FirstNode;`

Comment: Then I am doing `foreach (XElement book in rootNode.Nodes())`

Comment: @Leany: cut out the middleman. You don't really need XDocument at all, simply use `XElement rootNode = XElement.Load("data.xml")`

Comment: oh, that worked! I replaced `foreach (XElement book in rootNode.Nodes())` with  `foreach (XElement book in rootNode.Elements())`. So, is `XNode` an alternative to `XElement`?

Comment: @Leany: You can read more about them [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/086c5273-32eb-48d7-999f-74e31e6e531f/)

Comment: @alex thanks. Is it possible to do edit a book with a specific name using LINQ in a similar way you did for delete?

Comment: I mean, get an XElement that matches and change value.

Comment: @Leany: I edited my answer with a way to edit an existing element.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is reasonable small - i.e. not several MB in size - you should use either [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) (the classic way) or [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) (the new LINQ classes for XML processing). You will find lots of examples for both.
The following search results might give a hint as to when you should use which of those classes: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=XmlDocument%20vs.%20XDocument. Personally, I would suggest using `XDocument`, because its API is easier to use.