# Adding new node to existing XmlDocument object

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml of following format.

```
<BOOKS>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>book 1</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>author 1</AUTHOR>       
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK>
        <TITLE>book 2</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>author 2</AUTHOR>       
        <PRICE>20.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
    </BOOK>
</BOOKS>
```

I have an `Add(XmlDocument xDoc, Book newBook)` method to add new book to the `XmlDocument` object that is passed to the `Add(..)` method. How can I do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Data management in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974152/xml-data-management-in-net)

Comment: You already asked that question. Please consult the documentation provided in the answers to your last question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add an existing Xml string into a XElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414561/how-to-add-an-existing-xml-string-into-a-xelement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Data management in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974152/xml-data-management-in-net)

Answer (score 30):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");
XmlElement foo = doc.CreateElement("foo");
XmlElement bar = doc.CreateElement("bar");
bar.InnerText = "whatever";
foo.AppendChild(bar);
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(foo);
doc.Save("file.xml");
```

see ***Martin Honnen*** Post at: [Adding a new Node to existing XML document](http://p2p.wrox.com/xml/75531-adding-new-node-existing-xml-document.html)