# Xml File should create new line and leave the previous data

Tags: c#

How can I write an XML file so that it starts a new line and does not overwrite the previous data?

```
string pfad = "C:\\temp\\Accounts.xml";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Login");
XmlElement id = doc.CreateElement("user");
XmlElement username = doc.CreateElement("username");
username.InnerText = txtBenutzerName.Text;

id.AppendChild(username);

root.AppendChild(id);
doc.AppendChild(root);
doc.Save(pfad);
MessageBox.Show("Created SuccesFully!");
```

Comment: You're creating a completely new document - it sounds like you should load the existing XML file, append the new element, then save it again.

Comment: Welcome on Stacloverflow as 'original poster'. You probably do not want to create a new document. Open the existing one and add the node. Of course this has been asked before. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975114/adding-new-node-to-existing-xmldocument-object . Your question will be marked as duplicate (by someone with enough reputation).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a new document by this line

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
```

you should load existing file like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(pfad);

...below code is the same...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load("C:\\Accounts.xml");
  doc.GetElementsByTagName("username")[0].InnerText="sdkjfsdknfkds";
  doc.Save("C:\\Accounts.xml");
```